# LIKE doesn't return any record when used with SUBSTR

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

*coach_career*

```
coach_id | start      | end 
  483368   2017-01-01   NULL
```

*competition_seasons*

```
coach_id     | name 
   483368      2017/2018
```

I have wrote query:

```
 SELECT * FROM coach_career cr
          INNER JOIN competition_seasons s
          ON SUBSTR(cr.start, 1, 4) = s.name
          WHERE cr.id = 483368
```

Essentially I need to return the coach which have as `start` value the year  of `name` field available in `competition_season`, I used `SUBSTR` to extract only the year, the problem's that this query return no records.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT SUBSTR(cr.start, 1, 4) FROM coach_career` and `SELECT name FROM competition_seasons` to see if there are any matching values?

Comment: If I remove the SUBSTR the record is returned correctly, should be a mistake on SUBSTR

Comment: This is a date, so don't substring on it. Instead extract the year using `ON Year(cr.Start) = s.name` Unless you're storing your dates as varchar. In which case... ***YUCK***.

Comment: @JNevill You're right, I completely overlooked it, thanks..

Comment: Also.. your name value is `2017/2018`. You have two values in a single column. You are going to have a bad time here. Perhaps something like `ON s.name LIKE CONCAT('%', YEAR(cr.start), '%')` that's not going to be quick though. Ultimately you'd be better off storing two records in this table (one for each year/name).

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you check what does `SUBSTR(cr.start, 1, 4)` returns?

Comment: And how do you expect `2017 = 2017/2018` to return true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT * FROM coach_career cr 
INNER JOIN competition_seasons s
ON s.name LIKE concat('%', SUBSTR(cr.start, 1, 4), '%')
WHERE cr.id = 483368
```

will join the tables when `name` contains the value of `start`. 
If `start`'s data type is `date` then use `date_format()` to extract the year like this:

```
SELECT * FROM coach_career cr 
INNER JOIN competition_seasons s
ON s.name LIKE concat('%', date_format(cr.start, '%Y'), '%')
WHERE cr.id = 483368
```

Are you sure about using the condition:

```
WHERE cr.id = 483368
```

It does not seem right.

Answer (score 1):

if both are string values,

SUBSTR(cr.start, 1, 4) is equal to "2017".

s.name = "2017/2018".

The 2 values are NOT equal.